# Why is prefixing class, method, or variable names with "My" considered bad practice?

Tags: coding-style, naming-conventions, standards

Often in code snippets or examples, the prefix `My` is used for classes, methods, and variables.

We see this all the time, from [Google's gcm example](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart) to [numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242616/angular-js-1-3-11-argument-mycontroller-is-not-a-function) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480376/what-does-the-return-do-in-return-myfunction) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265661/how-to-use-arrayadaptermyclass) [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726962/how-to-use-stringutils-and-mystring-getting-cannot-resolve-error). It can be found in documentation for [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php), [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp), [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx), and really just about every other language.

So, given it's extreme prevalence, why shouldn't I put `MyClass` with `myMethod` using `myVar1` into production? Why is this bad practice, and what should I do instead?

Comment: The examples use "MyClass" because they can't use just "Class" -- it's a reserved word. Same for "Var", "Function" etc. And since they are samples, they say things like: "Let's assume you have a class called MyClass....." In YOUR code, name your class for what it represents. If it's a user you are modeling, the class name can be "User". If it's a car, maybe "Car", or more generically, "Vehicle". See?

Answer (score 1):

### Name are important

Everything else comes down to that one simple fact.

> Having clear, meaningful variable names is an important factor in writing understandable and maintainable code. - [Computational Fairy Tales](http://computationaltales.blogspot.com/2011/03/importance-of-variable-names.html)

When you write a piece of code, you want anyone reading it (which includes you in three months!) to know what it does almost immediately. In order to remember, you would probably need to add a comment about it. However...

> The proper use of comments is to compensate for our failure to express our self in code - [Express Names in Code: Bad vs Clean](http://blog.goyello.com/2013/05/17/express-names-in-code-bad-vs-clean/)

To help with this, your name should be both descriptive and concise. Generally, when the prefix `My` is added, it replaces a prefix that could be more informational. Instead of `MyService`, why not `GcmListenerService`?

**What if I make it descriptive, but I just add `My`? Like `MyGcmListenerService`?**

That breaks the consice part of the rule. What do you gain from adding `My`? Is the `My` adding value to the name? Even if you were attempting to take possession of the code (which would be better done and is feasible using [vcs](https://www.drupal.org/node/1146430)), `My` is meaningless. Who wrote `My`? *Well, I did, obviously. It says it right there, "My".*

**If I really shouldn't use `My`, why is it in so many examples?**

Really, it's just a placeholder.

> It's like the metasyntactic variables "foo" and "bar" - it's usually used as a placeholder for a real name. - [Opinions on using My as a class name prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394883/771665)

Unfortunately, most experienced programmers just assume that people looking up examples will know this, and they will replace `My` with a good variable name when they actually use the code. However, for those new to programming, if you see it all over the place, instead of knowing it is a placeholder, you may think it is actually a standard, and best practice to use `My`.

**Ok, then what do I use instead of `My`?**

There are a lot of really good guides about naming variables and classes out there. You can start with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)), but if you google around a bit you can find lots of articles about good vs bad names. At the heart of it all, though, is one rules: *make names descriptive, and keep them concise.*

If I read the name of a class, method, or variable and immediately know its purpose, it is a good name.